# Video set as div background, does not cover full width of the page

Tags: html, video, width

I am fairly new to web development, and I was trying to set the background for a specific 'div' to be a video. After extensive research, I succeeded in doing so, but the problem is that the video is not covering the full length of the page. Is there a way I can get the video to cover the full width of the page, just for that specific 'div' portion....?
Thanks ! :)

Here is the html code I used for inserting the video in the background...

```
 <header>

        <div style="position: fixed; top: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%; z-index: -1;background-size: cover; background-image:url(frame.jpg) no-repeat center top">
                <video id="video" style="width:100%; height:100%" autoplay loop>
                  <source id="mp4" src="Sea.mp4" type="video/mp4">
                </video>
        </div>
```

Comment: By full width I mean that there are still edges on either side of the video that are white. i tried decreasing the z-index value, removing the background colour (css), but all that didn't work...

Answer (score 0):

You're not applying correctly the `background-image` property value:

`background-image` accepts only the `url("")` (in your case), but not also the `position` and `size`.

Do like:

```
background: url(frame.jpg) center top / cover;
```

***[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/pupide/3/edit?html,css,output)***

also add

```
body{margin:0;}
```

to remove the default margin applied to `body`

Comment: Hi ! I had inserted this in the header, so I tried setting the margin to 0 for the header, but it didn't seem to work...

Comment: you know about the `body` tag, right? If `body` does not work try with `*{margin:0;}`

Comment: Yes. I tried what was done in the demo with the body tag now, but there are still white spaces to the side..                                                               body {
    overflow-x: hidden;
    margin:0;
}

Comment: @Shashank ahh I understand now you have an issue in setting your background image. I'll edit my answer in a sec.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the suggestion but it didn't seem work. The image, is just the first frame of the video. Shouldn't the video cover the width, regardless if the image is there or not ?

Comment: @Shashank as you can clearly see in my demo the video covers the width completely. If there's something else you don't understand please edit your own question.